# Property 'context' cannot be accessed on 'OverlayState?' because it is potentially null: Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, quill, rich-text-editor

I am making a Text Editor application in flutter and want to use-
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill
But, when I try to build the project after adding the dependency, I get the following error-

```
/D:/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.3.2/lib/src/widgets/toolbar/quill_font_size_button.dart:113:41: Error: Property 'context' cannot be accessed on 'OverlayState?' because it is potentially null.
- 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('/D:/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
    final overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                                        ^^^^^^^
/D:/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.3.2/lib/src/widgets/toolbar/quill_font_family_button.dart:112:41: Error: Property 'context' cannot be accessed on 'OverlayState?' because it is potentially null.
- 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('/D:/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
    final overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
                                        ^^^^^^^
/D:/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_quill-6.3.2/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:87:61: Error: The argument type 'OverlayState?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider' because 'OverlayState?' is nullable and 'TickerProvider' isn't.
- 'OverlayState' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart' ('/D:/flutter_windows_2.10.5-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/overlay.dart').
```

SDK Versions are-

```
compileSdkVersion 33
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
minSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 33
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: The application is moving to outside of current context , try to save or pass your context from the Widget build to this. Sharing the code would clarify how you are calling the function.

Comment: @Ahmad This issue occurs during build. same in iOS build

Comment: Issue added - https://github.com/singerdmx/flutter-quill/issues/1083

Comment: @김상현 context in flutter is different from Android and IOS. It has its own context and environment within the os level.

Comment: @coder001 From the github link Launching lib\main.dart on SM M215F in debug mode , so its not compile time error rather runtime error IMO. Getting to see the dart file where its been called and how its been called could help.d

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue now T^T
anyone can solve this problem

Comment: same issue, on flutter v3.3.2... after flutter clean, and Android Studio cache invalidate !!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just update the flutter version to latest stable version 3.7.0. The build error will disappear.

```
flutter upgrade
```